# Json tree output

Tags: php, json

I want to change this json output to below style, Any ideas?

My Code:

```
$queryFunctions = $db->getChatRoomData($userID , $userName, $userMessage, $roomID);
$rows['roomInfo'] = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queryFunctions, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
       {
               $row['uid'] = $result['uid'];
               $row['name'] = $result['userName'];
               $row['message'] = $result['messageText'];
               array_push($rows, $row);

        }
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Current Output :

```
{"roomInfo":[],"0":{"uid":"50","name":"ali","message":"arz adab !"},"1":{"uid":"50","name":"ali","message":"arz adab !"},...}
```

Desired Output :

```
{"roomInfo" : [{"uid":"50","name":"ali","message":"arz adab !"},{"uid":"50","name":"ali","message":"arz adab !"},...}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: your desired output isn't valid JSON. You must enclose the whole string with `{}`: you can't have a bare top-level attribute

Comment: Why would you want this? it's not valid JSON. You always need to have an { object } as the main output of your JSON or need at least a  [ array ] as the top element... And then again, not even sure, if array can be top level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `push` the data to `roomInfo` key over your rows.

```
$queryFunctions = $db->getChatRoomData(
    $userID , $userName, $userMessage, $roomID
);
$rows = array('roomInfo' => array());
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queryFunctions, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $row['uid'] = $result['uid'];
    $row['name'] = $result['userName'];
    $row['message'] = $result['messageText'];
    array_push($rows['roomInfo'], $row);

}
print json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, then what you want is to create an array with a key "roominfo" that maps to an array of roominfos.

```
$queryFunctions = $db->getChatRoomData($userID , $userName, $userMessage, $roomID);
$rows['roomInfo'] = array();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($queryFunctions, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    $row['uid'] = $result['uid'];
    $row['name'] = $result['userName'];
    $row['message'] = $result['messageText'];
    array_push($rows['roomInfo'], $row);

}
echo json_encode($rows);
```